# How to make my SLComposeViewController available for service type (Facebook) iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-share

I have just gone through adding all the required Facebook frameworks, adjusting my info.plist, and adding methods in my app delegate to allow users to sign in using Facebook. I have even tested and verified this new data on my parse database. Yay.

Now, I'm trying to add a button that shares info to the user's newsfeed if they logged onto my app with Facebook. Here's what I have:

```
@IBAction func tellFriends(sender: AnyObject) {

    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {  // USER LOGGED IN USING FACEBOOK

        let facebookSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        facebookSheet.setInitialText("Share on Facebook")
        self.presentViewController(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {  // USER DID NOT USE FB TO LOG IN

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

The only result I get is the else and my alert controller pops up. I verified I am logged into the app with Facebook. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just kidding, this code works, just not in the simulator. Once I plugged in my phone and tried it on there it worked fine. Much like with location services, notifications and message UIs; they work on an actual iPhone, and not in the simulator.